# joining tables in a query

Tags: sql

I have a set of tables which basically look like this

```
AGENCY
- AGENCY_NAME
- AGENCY_ID

AGENT
 - AGENT_NAME
 - AGENT_ID
 - AGENCY_ID

ITEM
 - ITEM_NAME
 - ITEM_ID
 - AGENT_ID
```

The ITEM is mapped to the AGENT and the AGENT is mapped to an AGENCY.

I need to be able to select all items for a given agency, what I give as input is an AGENT_ID.  I know how to get all by agent only, but I can't figure out how to write a single query that will return all ITEMS which belong to agents within the given agent's agency.  I can do it with nested selects but I was wondering if there was a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joining to `AGENCY` through `AGENT` will allow you to supply an `AGENCY_ID` into the `WHERE` clause and return all `ITEM`s for agents belonging to that agency:

```
SELECT 
  ITEM_NAME,
  ITEM_ID
FROM 
  ITEM
  JOIN AGENT ON ITEM.AGENT_ID = AGENT.AGENT_ID
  JOIN AGENCY ON AGENT.AGENCY_ID = AGENCY.AGENCY_ID
WHERE AGENCY.AGENCY_ID = 'your_input_id'
```

As an added bonus, you can add additional info about the agent here, since `AGENT` is joined in...

```
SELECT 
  ITEM_NAME,
  ITEM_ID,
  AGENT_NAME
FROM 
  ITEM
  JOIN AGENT ON ITEM.AGENT_ID = AGENT.AGENT_ID
  JOIN AGENCY ON AGENT.AGENCY_ID = AGENCY.AGENCY_ID
WHERE AGENCY.AGENCY_ID = 'your_input_id'
```

Comment: I actually need to query by agent_id not agency_id.

Comment: @RockyTriton You'll need a subselect somewhere then, either in the `WHERE` clause, or in a derived table join.

Comment: ok thanks, that was my original plan but I was wondering if it could be avoided somehow.

Answer (score 0):

I interpret this to say that you want, for a given agent (specified by agent_id), you want all the items for all the agents that belong to the agency that the given agent belongs to.

So, this would be:

```
select i.* 
from item i
join agent a 
  on i.agent_id = a.agent_id
join agency ag
  on ag.agency_id = a.agency_id
where ag.agency_id = 
   (select agency_id from agent a2 
    where a2.agent_id = 'my_agent')
```

You can't avoid a sub-query (nor is it really an issue that there is one).

Answer (score 0):

Two options. I like the nested version, because to me it reads a bit clearer. Both asssume parameter @AGENTID as your "starting" agent, and use SELECT DISTINCT to remove duplicate items.

```
--  Nested/subquery: pick out all agents (and their items)
--  in the same agency as your target agent
SELECT distint it.ITEM_ID, it.ITEM_NAME
 from AGENT agt
  inner join ITEM it
   on it.AGENT_ID = agt.AGENT_ID
 where agt.AGENCY_ID = (select AGENCY_ID
                         from AGENT
                         where agt.AGENT_ID = @AGENT_ID)
```

and

```
--  No nesting: Start with target agent, join to all agents
--  (including themselves) in the same agency, and on to
--  all their items
SELECT distint it.ITEM_ID, it.ITEM_NAME
 from AGENT agt
  inner join AGENT agt2
   on agt2.AGENCY_ID = agt.AGENCY_ID
  inner join ITEM it
   on it.AGENT_ID = agt2.AGENT_ID
 where agt.AGENT_ID = @AGENT_ID
```